# error XA2006: Could not resolve reference to 'System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectionHandler' (defined in assembly 'System.Web

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-mvc, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to build an app where I'm trying to add the references to the old MVC projects. While doing so I have faced some issues like unable to resolve some references. So, I have added them manually which helped me build the project but facing the below issue while deploying it.

Can someone help me out, please?

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1881,5): error XALNK7000: Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006: Could not resolve reference to 'System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectionHandler' (defined in assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a') with scope 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. When the scope is different from the defining assembly, it usually means that the type is forwarded. ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectionHandler
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1881,5): error XALNK7000:   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedType (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference reference) [0x00013] in <4f0a19c9d0ec417f9e44b588fd30d062>:0
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1881,5): error XALNK7000:   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference reference) [0x0002c] in <4f0a19c9d0ec417f9e44b588fd30d062>:0
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1881,5): error XALNK7000:   at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference reference) [0x00000] in <4f0a19c9d0ec417f9e44b588fd30d062>:0
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1881,5): error XALNK7000:   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInterfaceImplementation (Mono.Cecil.InterfaceImplementation iface) [0x0000e] in <4f0a19c9d0ec417f9e44b588fd30d062>:0
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1881,5): error XALNK7000:   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkEntireType (Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinition type) [0x00076] in <4f0a19c9d0ec417f9e44b588fd30d062>:0
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1881,5): error XALNK7000:   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkEntireAssembly (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly) [0x0003a] in <4f0a19c9d0ec417f9e44b588fd30d062>:0
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1881,5): error XALNK7000:   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeAssembly (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly) [0x00045] in <4f0a19c9d0ec417f9e44b588fd30d062>:0
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1881,5): error XALNK7000:   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Initialize () [0x00014] in <4f0a19c9d0ec417f9e44b588fd30d062>:0
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1881,5): error XALNK7000:   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x00007] in <4f0a19c9d0ec417f9e44b588fd30d062>:0
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1881,5): error XALNK7000:   at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x0000b] in <4f0a19c9d0ec417f9e44b588fd30d062>:0
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1881,5): error XALNK7000:   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context, Mono.Linker.Steps.IStep step) [0x0000d] in <4f0a19c9d0ec417f9e44b588fd30d062>:0
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1881,5): error XALNK7000:   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x0000f] in <4f0a19c9d0ec417f9e44b588fd30d062>:0
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1881,5): error XALNK7000:   at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Run (Mono.Linker.Pipeline pipeline, Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x00000] in <4f0a19c9d0ec417f9e44b588fd30d062>:0
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1881,5): error XALNK7000:   at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process (MonoDroid.Tuner.LinkerOptions options, Mono.Linker.ILogger logger, Mono.Linker.LinkContext& context) [0x00071] in <4f0a19c9d0ec417f9e44b588fd30d062>:0
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1881,5): error XALNK7000:   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute (Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver res) [0x001dd] in <4f0a19c9d0ec417f9e44b588fd30d062>:0
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1881,5): error XALNK7000:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1881,5): error XALNK7000:   at Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.Diagnostic.Error (System.Int32 code, System.Exception innerException, System.String message, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/204/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics/Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics/Diagnostic.cs:166
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1881,5): error XALNK7000:   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute (Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver res) [0x00276] in <4f0a19c9d0ec417f9e44b588fd30d062>:0
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1881,5): error XALNK7000:   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.RunTask () [0x0001b] in <4f0a19c9d0ec417f9e44b588fd30d062>:0
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1881,5): error XALNK7000:   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute () [0x00000] in <4f0a19c9d0ec417f9e44b588fd30d062>:0

Comment: it sounds like you are referencing libraries that have dependencies that do not exist in Xamarin

Comment: @Jason I have added all those assemblies referenced by the MVC projects. But still, it's not working.